# Mirage 2 theme with DSpace 3.2

Tags: themes, dspace

Is Mirage 2 theme (http://atmire.com/website/?q=download-mirage-2) compatible with DSpace 3.2 version? Is there another responsive theme for this version of DSpace?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the [mirage2 github](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/master/dspace-xmlui-mirage2) page it says

> Mirage 2 is a responsive XMLUI theme for DSpace 4

(Though it does also work for later versions.)

If you want to use DSpace 3.2 I don't think there is a readily available repsonsive theme. But you can, of course, alter a theme yourself and make it responsive. You could use the current version of mirage2 for inspiration. Note that whilst the beta versions of Mirage2 did work under DSpace3.2, I don't think it is a straightforward port from the current version of Mirage2.